# RewriteRule on virtual subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to create virtual subdomain but i have no idea.can you please help me for create virtual subdomain in htaccess file

Enter url => demo.flexxm.mobi

Load url  => http://flexxm.mobi/index.php?controller=subdomain&task=subdomain&subdomain=demo

i want to enter url "demo.flexxm.mobi" but execute task on this url "http://flexxm.mobi/index.php?controller=subdomain&task=subdomain&subdomain=demo".

I really need your help

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The simplest way will cause a redirect and reveal the rewritten URL. Do you accept that?

Answer (score 1):

In first you should add demo.flexxm.mobi as alias for domain and server of flexxm.mobi
This is impossible make in .htaccess. You should change settings in httpd.conf or use youe hosting control panel or contact with your hosting support.

In result for both domains should open same page.

Then you can configure .htaccess for your rewrite.

For example

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo.flexxm.mobi$ [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /index.php?controller=subdomain&task=subdomain&subdomain=demo [L]
```

There we add condition that rule work only if we get any page from demo.flexxm.mobi

Comment: Hello newman, "index.php?controller=subdomain&task=subdomain&subdomain=demo" ,"demo"is not fix it dynamic so how is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?controller=subdomain&task=subdomain&subdomain=demo/$1 [L]

IndexIgnore *